# Why does my self-bound generic type not match the method invocation?

Tags: java, generics

I'm writing code for a command shell that looks like this:

```java
interface Context<C extends Context<C>> {}

interface RecursiveContext<C extends RecursiveContext<C>> extends Context<C> {
  Shell<C> getShell();
  default Result execute(Command cmd) { return getShell().execute(cmd, this); }
}

interface Shell<C extends Context<C>> {
  C newContext();
  Result execute(Command cmd, C context);
}
```

I'm getting an error in the default method saying

```
The method execute(Command, C) in the type Shell<C> is not applicable for the arguments (Command, RecursiveContext<C>)
```

I expect this to work, since the `Shell<C> getShell()` is guaranteed to be able to accept `C` in its `execute` call and because `this` is in fact guaranteed to be a subtype of the same self-bound type `C`, but the compiler does not seem to agree with me. Where's the mismatch, and is it safe to perform a cast in the default method? If this is not safe, can you provide a counterexample of type mismatch?

I've also tried introducing an intermediate type in the shell `<D extends C> execute(Command, D)`, but that doesn't seem to change anything.

(Most of the suggested questions involve a raw-type intermediate step, but I don't think that I've missed that.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The core of the problem here is that `C` in `RecursiveContext` is not really `Self` - the type of the implementing class. There is no such thing in Java, and this `RecursiveContext<C extends RecursiveContext<C>>` is merely a trick to workaround that, and this is where that trick breaks.

Let's say I have `A` and `B`. This is valid:

```
class A implements RecursiveContext<B> {

    @Override
    public Shell<B> getShell() {
        return new ShellB();
    }
}
class B implements RecursiveContext<B> {

    @Override
    public Shell<B> getShell() {
        return null;
    }
}

class ShellB implements Shell<B>{
    @Override
    public B newContext() {
        return new B();
    }

    @Override
    public Result execute(Command cmd, B context) {
        return new Result();
    }
}
```

And I can do this:

```
new A().execute(new Command());
```

Now `execute` would pass `this`, which is an instance of `A`, into `ShellB.execute`!

Would anyone actually implement `RecursiveContext` like that? I would think not! *People* understand this `RecursiveContext<C extends RecursiveContext<C>>` pattern and "takes the hint". The compiler doesn't (because self-bounded generic types is not technically a language feature), and says `C` still might not be the same type as `this`.

Comment: So is the best I can do some defensive attempt at a cast/catching `ClassCastException` and dope-slapping the calling code for passing in a `Context` that was produced by the wrong factory?

Comment: @chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic- In my opinion, yes. I mean we are all humans, we know what this pattern means, hopefully. If `newContext` doesn't have side effects, I would do `getShell().newContext().getClass()` and compare that to `this.getClass()` to check this without an exception.

Comment: Hmm. Thanks. I'm considering instead making `newContext()` an implementation detail and eliminating the default implementation.

Comment: By the way, thanks specifically for the counterexample. That helped me understand exactly where the fault line is and make my design decision.

Answer (score 0):

I think its because

```
Shell<C> getShell();
```

does not reconcile C to Context.