# Kotlin Generics - recursive generic - casting the instance of erased type fails

Tags: java, android, kotlin, generics

When I iterate over a list of Sprites and check whether they implement UsesObjectPool or not, I am encountering these problems due to type erasure:

*If I try to check its type I get:

> Cannot check for instance of erased type: UsesObjectPool

```
  if(it is UsesObjectPool<Sprite>)
        {
            it.objectPool.releaseObject(it)
        }
```

- If I use the wildcard * to check, it says that:

> "required parameter Nothing, found Sprite & UsesObjectPool:

```
  if(it is UsesObjectPool<*>)
            {
                it.objectPool.releaseObject(it)
            }
```

*If I cast the it to UsesObjectPool, I get:

> Type argument is not within its bounds. Expected:
> UsesObjectPool Found: Sprite

```
 if(it is UsesObjectPool<*>)
            {
                (it as UsesObjectPool<Sprite>).objectPool.releaseObject(it)
            }
```

***The generic class and interface:***

```
interface UsesObjectPool<T> where T :UsesObjectPool<T>, T : Sprite
     {
         val objectPool: BaseObjectPool<T>
     }
    
abstract class BaseObjectPool<T> where T : UsesObjectPool<T>, T : Sprite
    {
        fun releaseObject(instance: T)
       {
          //Implementation
       }
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

The problem here is that you are not actually saying that `T` should be the implementing type (known as `Self` in some languages). As far as the Kotlin compiler is concerned, `T` can be any other type that implements `UsesObjectPool<T>`. This is why you can't pass `it` to `releaseObject`.

Here is an example:

```
class EvilObjectPool<T>: BaseObjectPool<T>() where T : UsesObjectPool<T>, T : Sprite

class Implementation : Sprite(), UsesObjectPool<Implementation> {
    override val objectPool: BaseObjectPool<Implementation>
        get() = EvilObjectPool()

}
class EvilImplementation : Sprite(), UsesObjectPool<Implementation> {
    override val objectPool: BaseObjectPool<Implementation>
        get() = EvilObjectPool()

}
```

Notice that this *compiles*. Generally we as humans recognise this "self-bound generics" pattern, and will never write something like `EvilImplementation`, but the compiler doesn't know that :(

Now imagine that `it` is `EvilImplementation`. `it.objectPool.releaseObject` would accept an `Implementation`, but you are giving it an `EvilImplementation`!

Anyway, I think you'd need to re-think your design, since Kotlin does not support `Self` as in some other languages.

See also [a similar problem in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64453876/why-does-my-self-bound-generic-type-not-match-the-method-invocation/64454979#64454979).

Comment: Interesting, and ridiculous at the same time.  Now I don't know how should I approach a new design. If you have any ideas or tips and if you'd add it to your answer, it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: @DeveloperKurt I would say that there is too little info to go off of here. For example, what is each of the types for and what do they represent? Why should `releaseObject` accept a `T`? I'd suggest asking a new question with more context included, specifically asking about how to redesign your model.

Comment: UsesObjectPool interface is used to distinguish between the Sprite types that are created and released by the object pool and not by the garbage collector. To be able to release them, the object pool for the type of the sprite does operations for both its sprite fields and its object pool's fields.

Comment: My personal opinion is, ditch `UsesObjectPool`, add a `releaseIfNeeded` method in `Sprite`. I'm starting to think that maybe this is more suitable on SoftwareEngineering.SE or Programmers.SE than on SO... @DeveloperKurt

Comment: I was thinking about your answer and I think there is a misconception regarding what T is. T is the SPRITE_TYPE. It is not going to extend BaseObjectPool, and the other ObjectPools won't have their own generic type, they will just pass the Sprite type to the BaseObjectPool.