# An object can hold an array of its own objects. But how does this work together with inheritance?

Tags: java, arrays, class, oop, generics

I have the following abstract class:

```
public abstract class Entity{
  private final ArrayList<Entity> parent;

  // a lot of code that is not important now
}
```

An instance of this class holds an ArrayList of "it's own objects". But how can I achieve the same thing for all subclasses of "Entity"? E.g. I have this class:

```
public class Player extends Entity {
   // a lot of code that is not important now
}
```

Now "Player" holds an `ArrayList<Entity>` but it should hold an `ArrayList<Player>`. This should be the same for all subclasses of Entity (there are a lot). My pseudo-code is: `ArrayList<THIS> parent`.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In practice, you can't do this. Java does not have this feature (self-types). In theory you can do this, but it comes with some limitations in order for it to be type safe.

Suppose you could do this, then I can write code like this:

```
Entity e = new Player();
e.parent.add(new SomeOtherKindOfEntity());
```

That doesn't make much sense, does it? `e` would have an `ArrayList<Player>`, but the compiler thinks that we can add `SomeOtherKindOfEntity` to it! So you can't use the type `Entity` as the type of a variable.

Here's another similar situation:

```
Player p = new SubclassOfPlayer();
p.parent.add(new Player());
```

Practically, you can use a generic parameter to work around this:

```
public abstract class Entity<T extends Entity<T>> {
  private final ArrayList<T> parent;

  // a lot of code that is not important now
}

public class Player extends Entity<Player> { }
```

Most Java programmers would recognise that the generic parameter is meant to be the same type as the subclass itself, [but the compiler doesn't](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64453876/why-does-my-self-bound-generic-type-not-match-the-method-invocation/64454979#64454979). This is why this is only a workaround, and not real "self types".

Answer (score 2):

you can achieve with this.

1. We declare a generic T, and then add a rule that this generic must extends the Entity class.
2. The class Player, extends from Entity, and then, can be used.

Following code ...

```
public abstract class Entity<T extends Entity> {
  private final ArrayList<T> parent;    
}

public class Player extends Entity<Player> {
}
```

Comment: It should (at least) be `Entity<?>`, otherwise you are opting out of generics.

Answer (score 2):

To achieve that, you can make your class `Entity` a *generic* class. Example:

```
public abstract class Entity<THIS extends Entity<?>> {

    private final List<THIS> parents = new ArrayList<>();

    public final List<THIS> getParents() {
        return parents;
    }

}
```

Your child classes now can look like this:

```
public final class Player extends Entity<Player> { ... }
```

Using it looks like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Player player = new Player();
    List<Player> playerParents = player.getParents();
    System.out.println(playerParents);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use **Object** as a type. All classes in Java are children of the **Object** class. The code:

```
public abstract class Entity{
 private final ArrayList<Object> parent;

 // a lot of code that is not important now
}
```

Then, when referring to the ArrayList you just need to cast it to the current class. Example:

```
(Player) parent.getItem(int itemNumber);
```

Comment: Then you are better off to leave `ArrayList<Entity>` as is. The type cast is still necessary, but at least the user is restricted to put only `Entity`s into the list.